# Can Automapper map from a Dictionary of properties to a flat destination?

Tags: automapper

Source contains a property bag in a Dictionary.  Can Automapper map the entries in the Dictionary to individual properties of the Destination based upon matching the dictionary keys with the names of the properties on the destination type?

Example:

```
public class Destination
{
    public int ProdNumber;
    public string Title;
}

public class Source
{
    public Dictionary<string, object> values = new Dictionary<string, object>();
}
```

where the values Dictionary will have two entries, one with a key of "ProdNumber" and one with a key value of "Title".  There will likely be entries in the dictionary that have keys that don't match any property in the Destination and they should be ignored.  There will be multiple properties of each primitive data type (int, string, etc) - so I presume I can't use a simple set of TypeConverters.

Any suggestions?
Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible at the moment, but it is planned for the next version.  Read this [thread](http://groups.google.com/group/automapper-users/browse_thread/thread/6788b2d85e498b3a) as it discusses the plans and a work around.

Comment: A year on did this get traction?